# D3 bar chart with large values

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, nvd3.js, c3.js

I have a d3 chart which is taking a large value of around 4k which is causing the bars to be very high.

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, y0])
    .range([dataY, 0])
    .nice();
```

How can i scale down the height of bars without affecting the real values.

Comment: Why not scale down the height of graph?

Comment: could u plz share working copy?. May i bit confused with the values in domain and range--!---